# Why does gedit need libbluray?

Tags: gnome, dependencies, gedit, blu-ray

Pardon me if this is something that "everybody knows," but gedit (the gnome gui text editor) has a dependency on libbluray.

I've googled and read the release notes for gedit, with no luck, and I can't for the life of me think of a legitimate reason for this.

I'm using RHEL7 Workstation, but I suspect any gnome DE will have this same strangeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gedit` package doesn’t depend on `libbluray` directly; it depends on [Gvfs](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gvfs), the virtual file system, and *that* can use `libbluray` [to retrieve Blu-ray metadata](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gvfs/tree/configure.ac#n473). The RHEL package is built with this support in place, which is why you end up needing `libbluray` to install the `gedit` package (indirectly).